# JWT setup do I have to use the CLI?

Tags: connected-apps

I am building a web based app which posts data to Salesforce. I have built this and the data transfers correctly as expected. However I need to advise clients on the setup required at their end. According to the steps here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_auth_jwt_flow.htm#sfdx_dev_auth_jwt_flow I must still create the offline app folders and then in step 4 authorise the app.

If a client has already setup the ConnectedApp with my Server certificate, are steps 3 and 4 definitely required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps 3 and 4 in the linked documentation are specific to performing JWT authentication in the context of a Salesforce DX development project using CI/CD.

To facilitate your remove server authenticating into Salesforce, the client would need to set up (*and preauthorize*) the Connected App, and provide you with the Consumer Key and the private key corresponding to the Certificate if you do not already have those values.

Your application can then perform a JWT authentication into their org using whatever JWT authentication tool you prefer, which could be calling SFDX or more likely directly executing the JWT flow in whatever language you prefer (libraries are available for many languages). You'll connect using a username that belongs to one of the client's preauthorized Profiles or Permission Sets, the certificate, and the consumer key.

Comment: Great - so I believe you're saying (for my context) no steps 3 and 4 aren't required. The only question would be how the user pre-authorises the app please?

Comment: It's steps 14 through 16 in the document linked under [step 2](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_auth_connected_app.htm). Your app should be shipping a Permission Set that the client can preauthorize.

Comment: Ah - that section - yes I would ask them to do that anyway. I just assumed the app needed separately approving. In which case great! Thanks for your answer.